# Trouble Pulling Date Using Pandas & Datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert dates and times to decimals.  The process works on another file, but for one set of files I'm working with, I'm running into trouble:

In the column "Time" the data output is:

```
>>> print rawtime
```

10/18/2016    13:31:44.079
10/18/2016    13:31:44.089
10/18/2016    13:31:44.099
10/18/2016    13:31:44.109
10/18/2016    13:31:44.119
10/18/2016    13:31:44.129
10/18/2016    13:31:44.139
10/18/2016    13:31:44.149
10/18/2016    13:31:44.159
10/18/2016    13:31:44.169
10/18/2016    13:31:44.179
10/18/2016    13:31:44.189
10/18/2016    13:31:44.199
10/18/2016    13:31:44.209
10/18/2016    13:31:44.219
...
10/21/2016    09:16:50.968
10/21/2016    09:16:50.978
10/21/2016    09:16:50.988
10/21/2016    09:16:50.998
10/21/2016    09:16:51.008
10/21/2016    09:16:51.018
10/21/2016    09:16:51.028
10/21/2016    09:16:51.038
10/21/2016    09:16:51.048
10/21/2016    09:16:51.058
10/21/2016    09:16:51.068
10/21/2016    09:16:51.078
10/21/2016    09:16:51.088
10/21/2016    09:16:51.098
10/21/2016    09:16:51.108
Name: Time, Length: 19113432, dtype: object

but when I try to use the strptime function, it says the format is wrong:

```
>>> t = datetime.strptime(rawtime[0], '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\bbaumgartner\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '13:31:44.079' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f'

Likewise, printing just the time column removes the date

> > > print rawtime[0]
> > >       13:31:44.079

Comment: Please do not use image to post your data as it is impossible to copy and paste your data and command from images and reproduce your result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to capitalize the "y"

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('10/18/2016 13:31:44.079', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

> datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 18, 13, 31, 44, 79000)